# Using a string variable in a list object range excel vba

Tags: vba, object, range

Could I please have some help with the following. I have a table which holds information that I then run through a loop to create a number of schedules. I have recently started working on a scenario manager that allows me to pick and chose the table that I use to feed my data assumptions using my debttable variable (see below).

The problem is that in the initial loop I have to physically have the table name in my range - see CombinedDebtFacilities. Is there a way to get around this?

Thanks

```
Sub debtcontrol()

CtrlSheet = "Control"
CtrlData = "ControlData"
DebtTable = Range("Debt_Scenario_Table'").Value

debtsheet = "Debt Calcs"
debtref = "'Debt Calcs'!"

'set the workbook and object values

Set CtrlWs = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(CtrlSheet)
Set DebtWs = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(CtrlData)
Set lo = DebtWs.ListObjects(DebtTable)
fcllength = lo.Range.Rows.Count

For i = i To fcllength

FclFund = lo.Range(i, [Combined_DebtFacilities[[#All],[Fund]]].Column)

Next I
```

Comment: I don't reference the data body range as I want to bring in all the results in the table, even if they may be blank, including the headers.  What I am wanting to get rid of is the Combined_DebtFacilities part of the syntax.

Comment: It is unclear what you actually want to do.  You can iterate over the column of a ListObject (including the header) like this `lo.ListColumns("Fund").Range.Cells(i)`

Comment: `[Combined_DebtFacilities[[#All],[Fund]]].Column` is equivalent to `Range("Combined_DebtFacilities[[#All],[Fund]]").Column` .   You can substitute table names like this
 `Range(SomeTable & "[[#All],[Fund]]").Column`

Comment: The Combined_DebtFacilities table name reference in the range needs to change depending on the table chosen in the scenario manager cell in a worksheet. I believe that your iteration over the column listobject is the solution I am after I will check this.

Comment: Is that table different from `lo`?

Comment: Yeah the list object name changes based on my selection in the cell I have chosen as the scenario manager, but the name of the table in the range doesn't. I believe your first suggestion works. Thanks!!

Comment: Glad that I could help.